# Ninject 3.0 (NuGet) with ASP .NET WebForms not calling WebActivator

Tags: asp.net, ninject, webactivator, ninject.web

I created a brand new WebForm site (VS2010) and added Ninject.Web (3.0) from NuGet...
It created NinjectWeb and NinjectWebCommon on App_Start... Its compiling fine, but it never exeute the code ...

Am I suppose to do something to get WebActivator work with WebForms?

I done the same process with MVC 3 project, and It worked fine...

Any idea why its not working in WebForms?

ps.: it seems to not recognize the App_Start

Comment: Which .NET Framework and IIS Version do you use?

Comment: I´m using .NET 4.5 and IIS Express for both (MVC and WebForms projects) in VS 2012 ... Also tried with  .NET 4.0 in VS 2010 without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try removing and then re-adding web activator via Nuget, if that fails you could always initialize your Ninject code in global.ascx.cs